# Help With Proving a Sequence Has a Limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have the following sequence:
$$a_{1}\in \mathbb{R}$$
$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}:a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}a_{n}+1$$
Now, I need to prove it has a limit and find it. I've tried to use Weierstrass theorem, to prove that it's bounded and that it's monotonic to prove it has a limit.

Proving it's bounded by $a_{1}+1$ was easy using induction, but I can't seem to prove it's monotonic:
$$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\frac{1}{2}a_{n}+1-a_{n}=-\frac{1}{2}a_{n}+1$$
And then I don't know how to continue to prove it's $>/<0$ since $a_{n}$ can be a negative when $a_{1}$ is chosen to be negative.

How should I continue from here?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my main language so I've probably chosen the wrong translation :) And yes bounded

Comment: I've fixed the problematic words, I hope now it's better

Comment: $x\to \frac{x}{2}+1$ is a contraction. Apply Banach's theorem and you are done.

Comment: I improved the typesetting but wasn't sure what you mean by $> / < 0$. Can you clarify?

Comment: Thank you, I've meant to write that I've tried to find if the difference is greater than zero to for increasing sequence or less than zero for decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side stepping the bounded and monotonic sufficient conditions, we can demonstrate convergence of the sequence directly.

Let $a_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}a_0 + 1$

$a_2 = \frac{1}{2} a_1 + 1 = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2} a_0 + 1 \right) + 1 = \frac{1}{4}a_0 + \frac{1}{2} + 1.$

$a_3 = \frac12 a_2 + 1 = \frac12 \left( \frac14 a_0 + \frac12 + 1 \right)+1 = \frac18 a_0 + \frac14 + \frac12 + 1.$

Prove by induction that the general term is given by:

$a_n = \frac{1}{2^{n}} a_0 + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} + \frac{1}{2^{n-2}} + \cdots + 1$.

Since $\frac{1}{2^n}a_0 \to 0$, we have:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{j}}$

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even think about trying that way, nice solution

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

$$a_{n+1}-2=\frac{1}{2}(a_n-2).$$
Thus, $$a_n-2=(a_1-2)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}\rightarrow0.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: it is $$a_n=2^{1-n}(2^n-1)+2^{1-n}C$$